# Complex conjugation in inner product space?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

I got the following derivation for some physical stuff (the derivation itself is just math)
http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/5215/12/12appendixD.pdf
I understand everything until D.8.

So in the eqation $\epsilon$ is a symmetric matrix and $\delta(x)$ is just the difference between two points

After D.7 they get the eigenvalue and eigenvectors from ε. The text says that my δx(t) gets aligned in the same direction as the the eigenvektor of the largest eigenvalue (this would be my explanation for the fact that there is no eigenvector in the scalar product, but this might be wrong, cause I do not know much about eigenvectors).
But what I don't get is why in D.8. my δx(t) is suddenly complex conjugated. I can not find the reason for this.
I would be really happy about any explanation.

have a nice day
ATY

PS: sorry for the weird titel. Had no clue how to describe my problem (mea culpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex conjugated in D6 come from the definition of inner product, in general if $A$ is a matrix, then

$$
\langle x | A y \rangle = \langle A^\dagger x | y\rangle
$$

where $A^\dagger$ represents the transpose complex conjugate of $A$.

As for the eigenvalues, note that D8 is taking the separation along the eigenvector of the largest eigenvalue, this is different to $\delta$ being aligned with such vector.

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply. You are totally right. I got confused by the notation.